# Read the xml files from the installed path

Tags: c#

I've created an setup files for my winform. When I run this setup file, the application will be install into the location specified by the user. The installation will also copy some xml files into that location. Right after the user run the application, it will read some settings from the xml files.

What I want to know is, because the location of the xml file is flexible (user specified), how do we know which location to read? How do we specified in the winform coding that it should read from the installed location?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at Application.ExecutablePath for the path where your exe was when it ran, so this would be the base directory of your install.

```
String startingdir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
foreach(String Filename in Directory.GetFiles(startingdir,"*.xml")
{
// process
}
```

Comment: Is there any example my friend?

Comment: Applicaiton.ExecutablePath returns a directory name in a string. so you can now search for xml files, or you probably know which ones you're looking for read them in ..

Answer (score 1):

Are the XML files copied to the same location as your executable? In that case, you can use `Application.ExecutablePath` from your WinForms app to get the location of the executable, and from there create the path to your XML files.

Comment: Yes, it is the same with my exe file after installation.

Comment: You can read them by a relative path. If the xml-files in the same directory, then you can read the files just by their name.

Comment: Is there any example my friend?

Comment: I've tried "reader = new XmlTextReader(Application.ExecutablePath);", but aren't doing this will only read the exe file? How do we write the coding to read the xml file?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this

```
reader = new XmlTextReader(Application.StartupPath + "\\MyFile.xml");
```

And it work fine!!

Answer (score 0):

If the files are copied to the working folder of your exe, then you can address them with relative paths (no need for absolute paths).

Edit: Here's an example

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load("filename.xml");
```

this piece of code will try to read the file *filename.xml* which is in the same folder that contains your exe file.

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load("somefolder/filename.xml");
```

and this one will try to read the file *filename.xml* from the folder *somefolder* that is located in the folder that contains your exe

Comment: Is there any example my friend?

Comment: I've tried "reader = new XmlTextReader(Application.ExecutablePath);", but aren't doing this will only read the exe file? How do we write the coding to read the xml file?

Answer (score 0):

The way i would suggest is you create a step in your installer where the user can set the location of the file. Put that in the registry . And get your application to read it from registry